# ReportViewer 10.0 loads page on report Paging

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a .NET 3.5 project. It used Microsoft Reportviewer 9.0. Paging was smooth . To accommodate printing in IE10, I updated the reportviewer control to version 10.0.

Now I see that paging has become substantially slow. Putting a breakpoint in the page_load , I observe that it was not getting hit in reportviewer 9.0, when navigating between report pages.
But in reportviewer 10, everytime I move to another page of the report, I see that the breakpoint in the Page_Load is hit.Happens irrespective of the reportviewer being inside an update panel or not. The experience is much slower than reportviewer 9.

Why is this happening ? Is there a way to improve the paging performance ?